# Windows Azure Cloud Service Not Loading

Tags: azure

I'm new to Windows Azure. I have an existing ASP.NET 4 MVC that is working. In fact, it works just fine as a Web Site within Windows Azure. I need to be able to RD into the site, so I decided to create a Windows Azure cloud service.

My Windows Azure cloud service is showing as running in the Windows Azure portal. My app is successfully published via Visual Studio. When I visit the Website URL listed in the Windows Azure Activity Log, I get an http status code of 502 according to Fiddler.

Can someone tell what's wrong? I can't figure out how to learn what's wrong from here.

Thank you!

Comment: Ping, please follow up on your own questions.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Error 502 error suggests Bad gateway.

So you can try below.

**Fixing 502 errors - general**

> This problem is due to poor IP communication between back-end
>   computers, possibly including the Web server at the site you are
>   trying to visit. Before analysing this problem, you should clear your
>   browser cache completely.
>
> If you are surfing the Web and see this problem for all Web sites you
>   try to visit, then either 1) your ISP has a major equipment
>   failure/overload or 2) there is something wrong with your internal
>   Internet connection e.g. your firewall is not functioning correctly.
>   In the first case, only your ISP can help you. In the second case, you
>   need to fix whatever it is that is preventing you reaching the
>   Internet.
>
> If you get this problem for only some of the Web sites you try to
>   visit then it is likely to be a problem at those sites i.e. one of
>   their pieces of equipment is failing/overloaded. Contact the people at
>   those sites.

For more information Check [**HTTP Error 502 Bad gateway**](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E502.html)

I hope this will help to you.

Comment: this happens from 4 different sources across the world... can't be a problem with each one's cache... must be something on Azure.

Answer (score 0):

In your web.config, set customErrors as

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="GenericError.htm" mode="RemoteOnly">
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="InternalError.htm" />
    </customErrors>
```

and browse the site using RD.

Or you could set it to

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="GenericError.htm" mode="Off">
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="InternalError.htm" />
    </customErrors>
```

and everyone who visits the site gets the stacktrace.